# verb to be in the end of a question`

Tags: word-order

I'm little bit confused.

What's the correct option?

> What do you think what is your best quality?

or

> What do you think what your best quality is?

If i have a question form with "do" in this part "what do you think..." should i reverse the verb to be and the subject?

I feel like second one is correct, but sounds weird. Not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct as written. This is one question, so there is no need to use the interrogative word "what" twice.

I believe you are trying to say:

> What do you think is your best quality?

OR

> What do you think your best quality is?

Regarding the placement of the verb "*is*", either way is acceptable, but ending the sentence with a verb is considered to be *informal* and found in the spoken word more often than the written. For example, in very formal speech people will say "*taking a walk*" rather than "*walking*" so that the sentence does not end on the verb, but this is not a rule strictly adhered to in colloquial spoken English.

Comment: Where I come from "taking a walk" and "walking" are equally formal/informal, and I never heard any rule against ending a sentence in a verb, even in formal writing.

Comment: @LorelC. It isn't a rule. If it were then one way would be incorrect. No, I thought I explained that one is considered formal. Ending clauses and sentences with a verb creates "top-heavy" sentences. Good writers try to place the verb as soon as possible after the subject of the sentence. Same goes for prepositions - it isn't wrong to end on one, but considered less formal.